# Re-render array of child components in React after editing the array

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I have data in parent's component state like this:

```
data=[
            {key:0,name="abc",value="123"},
            {key:1,name="def",value="456"},
            {key:2,name="ghi",value="789"}
     ]
```

In my react component I am calling child components as list in the return part of the parent component as shown below.

```
class MyApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      record={
        name="",
        timestamp="",
        data =[
          {key:0,name="abc",value="123"},
          {key:1,name="def",value="456"},
          {key:2,name="ghi",value="789"}
        ]
    }
    this.deleteFromStateArray=this.deleteFromStateArray.bind(this);
  }

  deleteFromStateArray(key){
    let oldData = [...this.state.record.data];
    let newData= [];
    oldData.map(function (record, i) {
      if (record.key != key) {
        newData.push(record);
      }
    })
    newData.map(function (record, i) {
      newData[i].key = i + 1
    })
    this.setState({ record: Object.assign({}, this.state.record, { data: newData }), });
  }
  render() {

  return(
    {
      this.state.data.map((record,index) => 
             <Child key={record.key}
              id={record.key}
              name={record.name}
              value={record.value}
              onDelete={this.deleteFromStateArray} />
    }
  )
  }
```

I am calling onDelete() in the child component like this 
`<button onClick={this.props.onDelete(this.state.id)} />
  \\ I am initializing id as key in state inside constructor in child`

My problem is when I am calling onDelete in the child class I am able to remove the obj with key=1 properly in the function but rerendering is not happening properly.

What I mean is state is getting set properly with only 2 items in data 1 with key=0 and other with key=2. But what i see in GUI is 2 child components 1 with key 0 and second one with key=1 which is cxurrently not present in the state data.

Can anybody help me with re-rendering the data properly?

> I also want to change the key ordering after deleting from array in setState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses `key` to work out if elements in the collection need to be re-rendered. Keys should be **unique** and **constant**. In your method you are changing `key` property of your records and this probably leads to described error.

Also, you can replace all your code with simple `filter` call like this:

```
this.setState(oldState => ({ 
    record: {
        ...oldState.record, 
        { 
            data: oldState.record.data.filter(item => item.key !== key)
        }
    }
});
```

It is also worth mentioning that you should keep your `state` as flat as possible to simplify required logic. In your case removing `record` and and leaving it as below would be a good idea:

```
this.state = {
    name: "",
    timestamp: "",
    data: [
      {key:0,name: "abc",value: "123"},
      {key:1,name: "def",value: "456"},
      {key:2,name: "ghi",value: "789"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is this syntax. can i get detailed info on what it is doing as i am new to react

Comment: ok, so instead of creating new array by` map` & `push` as you did I just used `filter`; then I modified your `setState` a bit to ensure it works on current state - more info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: will this syntax set state work only in JS file (mine is JSX) because i am getting error in visual studio code like `[js] Property assignment expected.
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this actually worked for you but the function declaration for `deleteFromStateArray` is inside the `render` function.

I think your component should look like this:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      record={
        name="",
        timestamp="",
        data =[
          {key:0,name="abc",value="123"},
          {key:1,name="def",value="456"},
          {key:2,name="ghi",value="789"}
        ]
    }
    this.deleteFromStateArray=this.deleteFromStateArray.bind(this);
  }

  deleteFromStateArray(key){
    let oldData = [...this.state.record.data];
    let newData= [];
    oldData.map(function (record, i) {
      if (record.key != key) {
        newData.push(record);
      }
    })
    newData.map(function (record, i) {
      newData[i].key = i + 1
    })
    this.setState({ record: Object.assign({}, this.state.record, { data: newData }), });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      {
        this.state.record.data.map((record,index) => 
          <Child key={record.key}
            id={record.key}
            onDelete={this.deleteFromStateArray} />
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: my bad the implemented way is like that only. I will correct my that in my question. But the problem remains the same

Comment: There must be something wrong with how you are removing the data. If you could add that piece of code then I can help you further.

Comment: sure, 1 minute.

Comment: i have added the same, but using react chrome extn i am sure the logic is working as i can see the data array in state after delete has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a built-in set function provided by react with state. See below for an example:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
const [data, setData ] = useState([]);
fetch('https://localhost:5001/getdata')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data)) // Example setData usage
    .catch((error) => alert)
```